# Can't include an HTML link in PHP script, but works fine as MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using the following as part of a PHP script:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table
SET description='<a href="http://123456.biz/index.php/123/321/456/*/789">text</a>' 
WHERE description IS null;");
```

The query works fine with MySQL, but I get the following error when running it as part of the PHP script:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'href' (T_STRING)

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont have PHP installed, can't test if this is working, please try the following:

```
   mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table
    SET description='<a href=\"http://123456.biz/index.php/123/321/456/*/789\">text</a>' 
    WHERE description IS null;");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your quotes are the issue. You're using double quotes (`"`) twice in the string and the parser is getting confused. Try escaping them instead with a backslash(`\`):

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table
    SET description='<a href=\"http://123456.biz/index.php/123/321/456/*/789\">text</a>' 
    WHERE description IS null;");
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

The value you are setting has double quotation marks. You need to escape these by using backslash \

This tells the script to use the characters as part of the value and not part of the script it's self.

### Solution

Just a simple mistake in your coding, try...

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table SET description='<a href=\"http://123456.biz index.php/123/321/456/*/789\">text</a>' WHERE description IS null;");
```

### Further Reading

[PHP AddSlashes](http://php.net/addslashes)

[PHP Escape Sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

[PHP Escape Special Characters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)